# jsfiddle not displaying my css

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am using jsfiddle for the first time, and it doesn't seem to recognize the css styles.  It also does not display the elements withing the  tag.

Here is the saved jsfiddle page for it: http://jsfiddle.net/s5LXc/

Is there anything that I did wrong there to get the unexpected result that I did?

Thanks!

Comment: I found no nav_bar class in the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5LXc/2/

You were missing your outermost `DIV` container with a class of "`nav_bar`".

Your HTML structure is also malformed in at least one place, such as (inverted `SPAN` and `FORM` tags):

```
<form name="form" method="post" id="header_search">


<span style='text-align: center; float: left;'>Search
    <input type="text" size="10" id="search_string">
    <input type="submit" value="Search"></input>
</form>

</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You show a class of 'nav_bar' but there is no such thing in your html.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong class in your nav container.

```
<div class="nav">
```

Instead of

```
<div class="nav_bar">
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing's for sure: you reference the class `nav_bar` a lot in your css, but it doesn't appear in your html at all.